# Detect/Handle incoming Credit Card Swipes at form level

Tags: c#, winforms, credit-card

I am working with a card swiper that, when a credit card is swiped, dumps the information into whatever has focus. This is a massive pain and effectively a "Copy/Paste" of the information read FROM the card TO whatever has focus.

Is there any way to handle the incoming "paste" at the form level through an event, regardless of what has focus?

Comment: You're asking how to paste the information. But how do you copy the information, do you have some code?

Comment: No. Basically the user swipes a credit card and everything on it, by the reader, gets dumped. I'm not looking to manually paste anything. I'm looking for a way to detect that whatever the card reader is doing is happening, and grab the incoming data before it gets splatted all over into some control with focus that doesn't need the incoming data.

Comment: Ok, but once the card swiper reads the card where are stored the info? Do you use any API?

Comment: It doesn't store the info. it's immediately dumped into whatever has focus.

Comment: I seriously doubt the device is performing a "copy/paste" operation. It's much more likely that it's simulating keyboard input, like other devices (for example barcode readers) do.

Comment: You probably want to disable the reader unless some specific form/field has focus, or switch focus when a card read is detected. Are you hoping to handle a swipe even if the application doesn't have focus for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above, the swiper works just like a keyboard (some of the more expensive have their own drivers with events).  So if you're on a webform, you handle it just like a keyboard event.  On the form capture the KeyUp event, and keep reading till you get the return code.

Comment: The first part of your answer is right, the second part isn't. Keyboard events go to the focused control. If one of the child controls has the focus, it will receive the text input, not the parent form. You should be overriding the form's `ProcessCmdKey` method.

Comment: Ah that's right - sorry, it's been a hot minute since I've done serious WinForm keyboard processing!

Comment: This was about what I had to do. I created a special form that was used to read the incoming data from the card reader. To access the form the user pushes a button, swipes the card, and clicks "Process", after which the information is passed to a function which handles it in the main form.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your card reader, at work had to deal with something similar:

Reader model with no options, just acted as a keyboard, used a 'read card' button that popped open a text input, you would use the card, and the OK button would put the content where it was needed.

Reader model with some options, was able to use manufacturer program to add a custom prefix and suffix around the card number, which the form could detect, then capture while suppressing the key presses from going further until the suffix or a timeout.

Reader model with SDK, software from manufacturer allowed it to be set as a non keyboard, and you just use the API to listen for card input in the background.  Also allowed fine grained beep and light control.

Comment: One additional point here is that many of the SDK models also allow you to keep encryption from device level throughout processing.  This can become a major concern with security.  Without that, you can face audits or liability from credit card theft from your system.